# Error generating SSL private key - Heroku - OpenSSL - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, openssl, private-key

I am following the instructions on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint but getting stuck on generating private key. It says to generate a private key '$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048' so I'm typing into rails command line

```
$ heroku run openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048
```

This seems to work and I can enter a passphrase twice (but there is no confirmation message)

The next stage is to type the following "$ openssl rsa -in server.pass.key -out server.key" - so that the private key can be stripped of its passphrase. So:

```
$ heroku run openssl rsa -in server.pass.key -out server.key

But here I get the following error:
Error opening Private key server.pass.key
2:error:02001002:system library:fopen no such file or directory:bss_file.c:356:f
open('server.pass.key','r')
2:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:358:
Unable to load private key
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

(by the way I already have site-wide SSL enabled on the app, using heroku's certificate. I am trying to change to my own SSL certificate for my own domain).

Comment: `no such file or directory` seems fairly clear to me.

Comment: yes it seems to be not generating the key but I don't understand why. There is no error message at the first stage.

Comment: It seems to be not *finding* the file you specified as *input.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the idea is to run those commands *locally*, on your own computer. First, make sure you have `openssl` installed (if you don't, follow the instructions on the provided Heroku help page, or use a friend's computer that has it installed). Then, type this:

```sh
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
........................................................................................+++
..........+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Enter pass phrase for server.pass.key:
Verifying - Enter pass phrase for server.pass.key:
```

After this step, there should be a file named `server.pass.key` in the current directory:

```sh
$ ls
server.pass.key
```

Then, run the second command:

```sh
$ openssl rsa -in server.pass.key -out server.key
Enter pass phrase for server.pass.key:
writing RSA key
```

After you finish this step, there should be two files in the directory. Then, continue as it says in instructions.

```sh
$ ls
server.key  server.pass.key
```

Comment: yup that was it. Also when generating the cert in openssl had to insert -config "C:\usr\local\GnuWin32\share\openssl.cnf" because I'm running on windows

Answer (score 2):

Check if your file is formed correctly.
I changed

```
-----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

into

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and the error disappeared.